# How to prevent loopback echo from mic to speaker in same pc

Tags: python, audio, gstreamer

I want to use my pc as a sound amplifier. Basicly capture audio from mic and play amplified sound from same pc's speakers. I'm using this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, Gtk
GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)

pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()

auto = Gst.ElementFactory.make("autoaudiosrc", "autoaudiosrc")
capsfilter = Gst.ElementFactory.make("capsfilter", "capsfilter")
capsfilter.caps = Gst.caps_from_string('audio/x-raw')
level = Gst.ElementFactory.make("level", "audiolevel")
level.props.interval = 50000000
audiosink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("autoaudiosink", "audiosink")

pipeline.add(auto)
pipeline.add(capsfilter)
pipeline.add(level)
pipeline.add(audiosink)

auto.link(capsfilter)
capsfilter.link(level)
level.link(audiosink)


class ProgressBarWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="ProgressBar Demo")
        self.set_border_width(10)

        vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)
        self.add(vbox)

        self.progressbar = Gtk.ProgressBar()
        vbox.pack_start(self.progressbar, True, True, 0)
        bus = pipeline.get_bus()
        bus.add_signal_watch_full(1)
        bus.connect("message", self.on_messages)
        pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)


    def on_messages(self, bus, message):
        t = message.type
        if t == Gst.MessageType.ELEMENT:
           structure = message.get_structure()
           if structure.get_name() == "level":
              rms = structure.get_value("rms")[0]
           if rms < -50:
              rms = -50
           rep = rms + 50

           self.progressbar.set_fraction(rep/50 + 0.1)
           self.progressbar.set_text(str(int(rms)) + " dB")
           self.progressbar.set_show_text(1)


win = ProgressBarWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

But when i run the python code and increase the speaker volume, playback becomes noisy and occurs infinite sound loops. I know this is physical because mic also captures speaker's sound again and again. But is there a pythonic or software based way to prevent this? Thanks.

Comment: You are doing exactly the thing that causes feedback. What are you trying to achieve; what do you want to amplify?

Comment: Actually amplifying sound is not my main objective. Basically only play audio that captured by mic.

Answer (score 0):

The feedback squeal can be avoided if you introduce a time delay, perhaps a FIFO  buffer. This way the rendered audio does not have a real-time forward feedback loop.